# How to display items side by side until window width then in next row

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some list of items in AngularJS scope variable. i want to display them in browser screen side by side upto window width, then in next row. They will look like this.

[image]

I want a padding of 5px; from all the sides between 2 items.

How to do that using bootstrap/css. Bootstrap will be preferred.

Comment: just wondering if any of the answers solved your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply by giving these items a `display: inline-block;` and a `padding: 5px;` to keep the gap you want.

Here's the code you need:

```css
.box {
    padding : 5px;
    display : inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: red;        
}
```

```html
  
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
```

You can resize the window to see the difference and how they behave dynamically.

Resize the result window in this [**DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/ewo9cL1L/1/) for best results.

Comment: float: left also do the job.

Comment: @cheziHoyzer yes it does.

Comment: Also, `vertical-align:top;` and similar values help with aligning the boxes.

Answer (score 3):

you can put them in a container (not necessary but can keep code cleaner) and set `text-align: center` on the container. Then each one of these can have a `display:inline-block` (if you want them all to be lined up centered, otherwise omit the `text-align: center` try doing that in the fiddle to see the difference)

keep in mind you have 2 options for the `margin` of `5px`, either you set only right or only left to have `5px`, or you set both right and left to be `2-3px`. If you want them to look more "centered" I suggest adding a right and left padding of about `2px` so it adds up to `4px`

you will get the result you see on [this page](http://dragndesign.com/ctdealsdesign).

or [**here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2c02fyp6/).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2c02fyp6/1/) without `text-align:center`.

Comment: There's no need to use a container.

Comment: @chsdk I agree but sometimes it makes things cleaner

Comment: Yes it whould be a better approach to wrap them inside a div or a container, but I just wanted to point out that the container is not necessarily needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below, hope you want this.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 500px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But when i am trying to do {{ 
<ul ng-repeat="product in Products | filter:{'scid': SCId.toString()}:true | orderBy:'pname'">
  <li>
  {{product.bname}}  
  <br>{{ product.pname }}
  <br>
  <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.image_path }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img>
  </li>
  
</ul>}}   Every product is displaying in new line, not side by side.

Comment: can you please show me the complete code in fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following CSS on the boxes:

```css
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you would like.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyIW/9v7ptryL/

use the boostrap `col-xs-2` class, inside a `row` class. all wrapped inside a `container` class. All `<div>`s.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
             <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
           <button class="btn btn-default"> btn 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 5</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 6</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 7</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
           <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
           <button class="btn btn-default">btn 8</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
<button class="btn btn-default">btn 9</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 10</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
            <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 11</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p> item </p>
           <img src="http://www.school-adventures.co.uk/expedition-photo-galleries/morocco/gallery/thumb_morocco_image15.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> 
            <button class="btn btn-default">btn 12</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .col-xs-2 {padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;}
    .row {margin-top:5px;}
    p {margin:auto; text-align:center;}

    img {margin:auto;}
    button {margin-top:5px;}
```